# AWS Api Gateway that integrated with S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to making a Server Side Rendering ReactJS app with AWS and I have to map some urls to S3.
for example: /assets

In Api Gateway I created a proxy resource and Integrate it with Amazon Services and select S3 and related Role and right now woking find when I testing it panel

**but**

When I deploy it to Stages and checking logs in CloudWatch below error shows exactly after data.

**Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to base64 decode the body.**

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

When you set **Binary Media Types** you must add ***/*** first and after that your necessary **Content-Type**s such as **text/html** and **application/json**.

Also if you are using Lambda to use React SSR you need to define BinaryTypes in **awsServerlessExpress** such as below:

```
const binaryMimeTypes = [
'application/json',
'text/html',
 ];
 const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app,null,binaryMimeTypes);
 exports.handler = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context)
```